# Inner Join using three table in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

**I try Association**

```
Currency_Info.hasMany(DEAL_INFO, {foreignKey: 'selling_CURRENCY'})
COUNTERPARTY_INFO.hasMany(DEAL_INFO, {foreignKey: 'COUNTER_PARTY_CODE'})
DEAL_INFO.belongsTo(Currency_Info, {foreignKey: 'selling_CURRENCY', targetKey: 'Ccy_Code'})
DEAL_INFO.belongsTo(COUNTERPARTY_INFO, {foreignKey: 'COUNTER_PARTY_CODE', targetKey: 'COUNTERPARTY_CODE'})



var conCursor = await DEAL_INFO
            .findAll({
               
                    include: [{model: COUNTERPARTY_INFO, required: true ,model: Currency_Info, required: true }]
              
              }) 
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.toString());
                res.status(400).send("-1" + error)
            })
```

**But didn't get desired result**

inner join CURRENCY on (DEAL_INFO.selling_CURRENCY = currency.CCY_CODE )

**How i get both the inner joins**
1.inner join CURRENCY on (DEAL_INFO.selling_CURRENCY = currency.CCY_CODE )
2.inner join counterparty_info on (deal_info.counter_party_code = counterparty_info.counterparty_Code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list of models inside the `include`

Something like this:

```
 var conCursor = await DEAL_INFO.findAll({
            include: [
               {model: COUNTERPARTY_INFO, required: true} ,
               {model: Currency_Info, required: true }
            ]
          }) 
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.toString());
            res.status(400).send("-1" + error)
        })
```

Hope you got your answer!